# How To Covert 7:00pm to Python Datetime object

Tags: python

I have a Schedule table with *start_time* column which stores time in this format,

**4:00pm**

**7:04pm**

**5:00am**

I want to be able to start an event for users base on the *start_time* they selected every day.

How do I convert **7:00pm** to `datetime` object or what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# time objects have no strptime method, so use datetime's, but it sets the
# date to 1900-01-01 by default
wrong_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('7:00pm', '%I:%M%p')
# replace 1900-01-01 with the actual date
correct_date = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), wrong_date.time())
# correct_date is now datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 22, 19, 0)
```

Comment: Works! Is this best the way to go about the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('2016-10-23 7:00pm')
```

Comment: Where is **pd** coming from?

Comment: Just edited. `import pandas as pd` is somewhat a convention when it comes to pandas.